# When using 2 y-axes, match X values

Tags: r, plot

To preface the question, I am aware that it is discouraged to plot 2 separate y-axes on a single plot, and that it can be confusing and misleading. However, I have to do it in this case, and am having some trouble having things line up. This area is commonly asked about, but I haven't seen any questions about how to do this when the x-indices are slightly off. Part of this may be due to my handling of POSIX & date objects, so if that fixes it please let me know.

I am trying to plot a time-series of soil moisture data, and compare it with precipitation and other parameters. I've tried to use ggplot2, but it doesn't appear very friendly to doing 2 y-axis plots. The data comes in 2 minute intervals, but processes on annual or larger time-scales are being used. An example of the dataset is below. There is some duplication, since the data comes with Year, Julian Day, and Minute but I combine them into a POSIXlt object for plotting and manipulation.

```
>to.analyze[1:10,]
Rowname Year    Julian_Day  Minute  T_.C.   Rel_Humid   Precip_.mm. T_5cm   T_10cm  T_20cm  T_50cm  T_100cm Moist_5cm   Moist_10cm  Moist_20cm  Moist_50cm  Moist_100cm TOD Year.Month  cumRain
2015.137.1  2015    137 0   18.85   19.83   0   31.88   30.08   25.66   21.36   20.6    0.046   0.054   0.07    0.125   0.134   5/17/2015 12:00:00 AM   2015.May    0
2015.137.2  2015    137 2   18.99   19.15   0   31.8    30.06   25.66   21.37   20.6    0.047   0.054   0.07    0.125   0.134   5/17/2015 12:02:00 AM   2015.May    0
2015.137.3  2015    137 4   19.12   20.3    0   31.72   30.03   25.69   21.37   20.6    0.047   0.054   0.07    0.125   0.134   5/17/2015 12:04:00 AM   2015.May    0
2015.137.4  2015    137 6   18.99   21.65   0   31.64   30.01   25.7    21.37   20.6    0.046   0.054   0.07    0.125   0.134   5/17/2015 12:06:00 AM   2015.May    0
2015.137.5  2015    137 8   18.68   22.59   0   31.55   29.98   25.72   21.37   20.6    0.046   0.054   0.07    0.125   0.134   5/17/2015 12:08:00 AM   2015.May    0
2015.137.6  2015    137 10  18.16   23.69   0   31.47   29.96   25.72   21.37   20.6    0.046   0.054   0.07    0.125   0.134   5/17/2015 12:10:00 AM   2015.May    0
2015.137.7  2015    137 12  17.69   24.8    0   31.38   29.93   25.75   21.37   20.6    0.047   0.054   0.07    0.125   0.134   5/17/2015 12:12:00 AM   2015.May    0
2015.137.8  2015    137 14  18.06   23.73   0   31.3    29.9    25.75   21.37   20.6    0.046   0.054   0.07    0.125   0.134   5/17/2015 12:14:00 AM   2015.May    0
2015.137.9  2015    137 16  18.39   22.97   0   31.2    29.88   25.77   21.37   20.6    0.046   0.054   0.07    0.125   0.134   5/17/2015 12:16:00 AM   2015.May    0
2015.137.10 2015    137 18  18.47   22.96   0   31.11   29.84   25.77   21.37   20.6    0.047   0.054   0.07    0.125   0.134   5/17/2015 12:18:00 AM   2015.May    0
```

EDIT: full data found here: http://dropcanvas.com/#Bl4hJG9Y4yfg5j (to large to paste)

The Year.Month value is a factor with n values, where n are the number of unique month/year combinations selected. I'm using this to get boxplots of monthly groups. I want to plot the raw data for soil moisture at a depth, then the boxplots of the monthly data on top of it, and then add on monthly precipitation bins. Monthly bins for precipitation come from:

```
short.sumRain <- aggregate(Precip_.mm. ~ Year.Month, to.analyze, sum)
```

The issue can be seen in the following plot.

```
plot(to.analyze$TOD,to.analyze[, "Moist_10cm"], xlab = "Time",
     ylab = "Volumetric Water Content", type = "l", xaxt = "n",
     main = main, ylim = c(0, .3))
r <- as.POSIXct(range(to.analyze$TOD))
axis.POSIXct(1, at = seq(r[1],r[2], by = "months"), labels = TRUE, format = "%Y-%m", 
         las = 1, cex = 0.1)

# Add boxplot
par(new = TRUE)
boxplot(to.analyze$Moist_10cm ~ to.analyze$Year.Month, range = 0, type = "l", 
    xaxt = "n", yaxt = "n", ylim = c(0, .3), boxwex = 0.3)

# Add monthly rainfall sums
par(new = TRUE)
plot(short.sumRain$Precip_.mm., type = "o", col = "blue", xaxt = "n", yaxt = "n",
 xlab = "", ylab = "", pch = 1)
axis(4)
mtext("Precip (mm)", side = 4, line = 1.5)
```

Which produces the following plot:
[image: VWC plot]

The precipitation label gets cut off a bit (not sure why R is doing that, but if line gets smaller it just appears on top of the labels), and the precipitation points don't match up with the tick-marks from the points plot. I think it is because the first plot is being drawn with a POSIX x-axis, and the other is not, but how can I get those 2 to line-up?

Comment: Could you provide that data in a reproducible format or use built in data for your example?

Comment: I put up the full dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the back ground of your problem is `POSIXct class`. `as.numeric( as.POSIXct("2011-01-01", "GMT") )` is 1293840000 and this is the real coordinate value. 
In default, `boxplot()` changes xy-coordinates and uses 1, 2, ~ as x-positions of them. Argument `add=T` makes `boxplot()` uses current coordinates and argument `at` gives the locations.
When you use 2 separate y-axes, it's safer to use the same `xlim`.

```
to.analyze <- read.csv("FMS.to.analyze.csv") # read the data

to.analyze$r <- as.POSIXct(to.analyze$TOD) # do class change first and add it as a new column
levels(to.analyze$Year.Month)       # I didn't use Year.Month because of alphabetical levels.
to.analyze$Year.Month2 <- substr(to.analyze$r, 1, 7)
# make a new column, Year.Month2 by extracting POSIXct class data
short.sumRain <- aggregate(Precip_.mm. ~ Year.Month2, to.analyze, sum)

x.range <- as.POSIXct(c("2013-05-01", "2013-09-01"))   # decide the x-range on plot
x.month <- as.numeric( as.POSIXct(paste0( unique(to.analyze$Year.Month2), "-15")) )
# decide the day where boxplot and short.sumRain's points are. (I used 15th of every month)
   # (paste0() joins year-month to -day. as.numeric(as.POSIXct()) calculate the real value.)

par(mar=c(4, 4.2, 2.5, 4.2))                           # set margin (down, left, up, right)
plot(Moist_10cm ~ r, to.analyze, xlab = "Time", xaxt = "n", ylab = "Volumetric Water Content", 
     main = "FMS", type = "l", ylim = c(0, .3), xlim = x.range)      # set xlim = x.range
axis.POSIXct(1, at = seq(x.range[1], x.range[2], by = "months"), labels = TRUE, 
             format = "%Y-%m", las = 1, cex = 0.1)
# you can draw additional other depth data by succeeding code.
# lines(Moist_100cm ~ r, to.analyze, col = "gray")

# use boxplot()'s arguments add=T and at. (If you don't want transparency, please delete col = "#00000020")
boxplot(Moist_10cm ~ Year.Month2, to.analyze, boxwex = 900000, 
        at = x.month, axes = F, col = "#00000020", add = T)

par(new = TRUE)   ### HERE, the first xy-coordinates are reset.
plot(short.sumRain$Precip_.mm. ~ x.month, type = "o", col = "blue", 
     axes=F, ann=F, xlim = x.range)           # use the same xlim
axis(4)
mtext("Precip (mm)", side = 4, line = 2)

# If you needn't keep TOD and/or Year.Mont, you can overwrite it 
# (e.g., to.analyze$TOD <- as.POSIXct(to.analyze$TOD) ) instead of making a new column.
```

[image]